# trimming leading tabs

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a `makefile` whose so-called "actions" are delimited by `\t`. When I need to execute these actions, the shell, of course, complains about `\tgcc -o a filename.c Coomand not found`. 
The search only yields how to trim leading/trailing tabs/spaces with `sed`. If, however, one is not allowed to use it, but only `bash`?

Example of such a "rule" is:

```
A : B C D E F G
\tgcc -o a A
```

`\t` here is only for clarity, in the actual file I press the tab key. What I need is to be able to read what follows after the tab character and execute it with `eval` or backticks. If I backtick what I read (i.e. without trimming the tab character off), the shell complains.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a makefile?

Comment: So you are saying your action lines actually start with a backslash character, followed by a 't' character, followed immediately by the actual command?

Comment: This seems to resemble an XY problem (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) problem; *why* are you trying to extract commands like this, since the purpose of a Makefile is to execute commands?

Comment: Can you post the actual error message. Cut and paste, don't retype it. I'm sure the shell is not actually complaining about the "coomand"

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to actually write \t on the command parts of makefiles.
Press the tab key to get the space needed.

```
A : B C D E F G
    gcc -o a A
```

EDIT -
If you are using vi/vim, you may be using a command that replaces TAB with a set number of
spaces (usually 4). Check that.

Comment: @llonpilaaja: And don't copy what I wrote. As I used 4 spaces instead of the tab key. You literally need the tab key.

Comment: He mentioned in his question that he is using tabs and only put `\t` in the question for show that he's using a tab.  A little confusing, but that's not the problem.

Comment: Didn't see the edit on his post. Anyways, if he's writing pure makefile from scratch, this problem really shouldn't be happening. I'm curious if the below answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use bash, then you need to parse the file, remove `\t` and dump to a new file.

Something like this;

```
while -r line; do echo "${line//\t/}" >> new_makefile; done < makefile
```